# For when the new Heroku1 service? There are out there any alternatives?

Tags: heroku, salesforce

Is there any expected date for Heroku1 be available? And what about alternatives? Alternatives or addons to use in Heroku, that have the sames functionality that Heroku1 will have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku Connect (Heroku 1) will be generally available at May 12.

Comment: Could anyone confirm this?